# In SQL Server how to get maximum of timestamp from each group which are not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have the below table structure

**alert_details_status** table:

```
alertTypeId macId     timeStamp     is_notified  escalation_status  alertType
123         13446   1547722123000       true       completed          408
```

**alert_details** table:

```
basicid alertType   alertTypeId alertDescription    macId     timeStamp   companyId     alertName            alertCondition  unitType   channelType  alertValue expectedValue
1234     406            123         testalert       13446   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50          60
1295     409            127         testalert       13448   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1298     409            128         testalert       13448   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1238     408            123         testalert       13446   1548148705000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1255     409            128         testalert       13448   1548135899000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1256     409            128         testalert       13448   1548135899000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
```

I am trying to group the `alertType`,`alertTypeId`,`macid` having maximimum `timestamp`(should return only one data per group if timestamp is same also) from alert_details which are not in alert_details_status. In two tables alertType,alertTypeId,macid should be different then only the result from alert_details having maximum timeStamp should appear for each group.

I am using the below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITINO BY alerttype, alerttypeid, macid ORDER BY timestamp DESC) RN 
     FROM 
         [test].[dbo].[alertdetails]) a 
WHERE 
    rn = 1 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT macId, alertTypeId, MAX(timestamp) 
                    FROM [test].[dbo].[alert_details_status] AS c  
                    WHERE a.macId = c.macId 
                      AND a.alertTypeId = c.alertTypeId 
                      AND a.alertType = c.alertType 
                      AND (is_notified = 'true' AND escalation_status = 'completed') 
                   GROUP BY alertTypeId, macId)
```

But it returns wrong data.

The final data I wanted is

```
basicid alertType   alertTypeId alertDescription    macId     timeStamp   companyId     alertName            alertCondition  unitType   channelType  alertValue expectedValue
1295     409            127         testalert       13448   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1238     408            123         testalert       13446   1548148705000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1256     409            128         testalert       13448   1548135899000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
```

Comment: What is the datatype of timeStamp   column?

Comment: timestamp datatype is numeric(19, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first calculating and then filtering the data, this can be the problem. You can try first filtering the data and then calculate it.

You can try query like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY t1.alerttype, t1.alerttypeid, t1.macid 
                   ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC) rn 
        FROM   alert_details 
               LEFT JOIN alert_details_status t2 
                      ON macid = c.macid 
                         AND t1.alerttypeid = t2.alerttypeid 
                         AND t1.alerttype = t2.alerttype 
                         AND t2.is_notified = true 
                         AND t2.escalation_status = 'completed' 
        WHERE  t2.alerttypeid IS NULL) t 
WHERE  t.rn = 1
```